# Passing object between flask requests, specifically intuit-oauth AuthClient

Tags: python, flask, session, quickbooks-online

I am trying to write a flask application to integrate with quickbooks online api, and am having trouble with authentication. Following their guide for python I have put together the code below. Currently my problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the AuthClient object between requests. I assumed I could just use flask sessions but the AuthClient object when recalled from sessions is incomplete, it only contains the shell and none of the populated data as far as I can tell.

Do I need to try to subclass the AuthClient and rewrite the methods used for pickling? If so any hints on how to get started there would be very helpful.

Also, if anyone has any experience integrating with quickbooks tips on that would be helpful.

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, request
from flask_session import Session
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from intuitlib.enums import Scopes
import os
import requests

SECRET_KEY = 'something'
DEBUG = True
REDIS_URL = 'redis://10.74.10.235:6379/0'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = DEBUG
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.config['REDIS_URL'] = REDIS_URL
sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)


@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    client_id = os.environ['CLIENT_ID']
    client_secret = os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET']
    redirect_uri = os.environ['REDIRECT_URI']
    environment = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']

    auth_client = AuthClient(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, environment)
    url = auth_client.get_authorization_url([Scopes.ACCOUNTING])
    session['auth_client'] = auth_client

    return redirect(url)


@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    auth_client = session['auth_client']

    state = str(request.args.get('state'))
    auth_code = str(request.args.get('auth_code'))
    realm_id = str(request.args.get('realm_id'))

    auth_client.get_bearer_token(auth_code, realm_id=realm_id)
    return 'boobs'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I was trying to save the wrong info. Found an example app that actually used the intuitlib module here. https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleOAuth2_UsingPythonClient/blob/master/app/views.py

Turns out instead of passing the AuthCLient around you recreate it each time giving it extra arguments as you acquire them such as:

```
auth_client = AuthClient(
    settings.client_id,
    settings.client_secret,
    settings.redirect_uri,
    settings.environment,
    access_token=session.get('access_token', None),
    refresh_token=session.get('refresh_token', None),
    id_token=session.get('id_token', None),
)
```

Saving just the tokens in the session.
Still having some troubles with getting the bearer token and a 400 error but this issue is resolved.